# PHP site reloads and doesn't process data - no errors

Tags: php, html, forms

I changed my form because I realized, what I did, didn't make sense. But now my PHP doesn't work anymore.
When I click the Submit Button, the site reloads and nothing has changed.
The PHP code wasn't changed. So I don't think, that it has a problem.

How the form was:

```
<form method="POST">
    <label for="text">
        <input type="text" name="zahla" id="zahla" placeholder="a">
    </label>
    <label for="text">
        <input type="text" name="zahlb" id="zahlb" placeholder="b">
    </label>
    <label for="text">
        <input type="text" name="zahlc" id="zahlc" placeholder="c">
    </label>
    <label for="text">
        <input type="text" name="zahlg" id="zahlg" placeholder="g">
    </label>
    <label for="text">
        <input type="text" name="zahlh" id="zahlh" placeholder="h">
    </label>

    <label for="text">
        <select name="mathe">
            <option value="drei">Dreieck</option>
            <option value="recht">Rechteck</option>
            <option value="para">Parallelogramm</option>
        </select>
    </label><br>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" id="abschicken" name="submit" value="=">
</form>
```

After it stoped working:

```
<form method="POST">

    <input class="zahl" type="text" name="zahla" id="zahla" placeholder="a">
    <input class="zahl" type="text" name="zahlb" id="zahlb" placeholder="b">
    <input class="zahl" type="text" name="zahlc" id="zahlc" placeholder="c">
    <input class="zahl" type="text" name="zahlg" id="zahlg" placeholder="g">
    <input class="zahl" type="text" name="zahlh" id="zahlh" placeholder="h">


    <select name="mathe">
        <option class="mathe-val" value="drei">Dreieck</option>
        <option class="mathe-val" value="recht">Rechteck</option>
        <option class="mathe-val" value="para">Parallelogramm</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" id="abschicken" name="submit" value="=">
</form>
```

The PHP didn't change a thing here:

```
<?php
/*Import Vars */
$zahla = $_POST['zahla'];
$zahlb = $_POST['zahlb'];
$zahlc = $_POST['zahlc'];
$zahlg = $_POST['zahlg'];
$zahlh = $_POST['zahlh'];
$mathe = $_POST['mathe'];

/*Kommahandler */
$zahla = str_replace(',', '.', $zahla);
$zahlb = str_replace(',', '.', $zahlb);
$zahlc = str_replace(',', '.', $zahlc);
$zahlg = str_replace(',', '.', $zahlg);
$zahlh = str_replace(',', '.', $zahlh);

/*Wandle Vars in Floats um */
$zahla = (float)$zahla;
$zahlb = (float)$zahlb;
$zahlc = (float)$zahlc;
$zahlg = (float)$zahlg;
$zahlh = (float)$zahlh;

/*Eigendlicher Code */
if ($mathe == "Dreieck") {
    if (empty($zahla) or empty($zahlb) or empty($zahlc) or empty($zahlg) or empty($zahlh)) {
        echo 'missing input';
    } else {
        $dr_um = $zahla + $zahlb + $zahlc;
        $dr_fl = ($zahlg * $zahlh) / 2;
        echo '<br>' .
            'Flächeninhalt des Dreiecks: ' . $dr_fl . '<br>' .
            'Umfang des Dreiecks: ' . $dr_um .
            '<br><img src="../pics/rechner/drei.png" alt="dreieck">';
    }
} elseif ($mathe == "Rechteck") {
    if (empty($zahla) or empty($zahlb)) {
        echo 'missing input';
    } else {
        $re_um = 2 * ($zahla + $zahlb);
        $re_fl = $zahla * $zahlb;
    }
    echo '<br>' .
        'Flächeninhalt des Rechtecks: ' . $re_fl . '<br>' .
        'Umfang des Rechtecks: ' . $re_um .
        '<br><img src="../pics/rechner/recht.jpg" alt="rechteck">';
} elseif ($mathe == "parallelogramm") {
    if (empty($zahla) or empty($zahlb) or empty($zahlh)) {
        echo 'missing input';
    } else {
        $pa_um = 2 * $zahla + 2 * $zahlb;
        $pa_fl = $zahla * $zahlh;
        echo '<br>' .
            'Flächeninhalt des Rechtecks: ' . $pa_fl . '<br>' .
            'Umfang des Rechtecks: ' . $pa_um .
            '<br><img src="../pics/rechner/para.png" alt="parallelogramm">';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what is your php code ?

Comment: @Al-Amin Sarker added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not set proper `vlaue` in your `if` condition. where comes from `select` area.

I changed

1. `if ($mathe == "Dreieck")` to `if ($mathe == "drei")`
2. `elseif ($mathe == "Rechteck")` to `elseif ($mathe == "recht")`
3. `elseif ($mathe == "parallelogramm")` to `elseif ($mathe == "para")`

Those value comes from...

```
<select name="mathe">
    <option class="mathe-val" value="drei">Dreieck</option>
    <option class="mathe-val" value="recht">Rechteck</option>
    <option class="mathe-val" value="para">Parallelogramm</option>
</select>
```

Now, I hope, this `php` code will help you.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*Import Vars */
    $zahla = $_POST['zahla'];
    $zahlb = $_POST['zahlb'];
    $zahlc = $_POST['zahlc'];
    $zahlg = $_POST['zahlg'];
    $zahlh = $_POST['zahlh'];
    $mathe = $_POST['mathe'];

    /*Kommahandler */
    $zahla = str_replace(',', '.', $zahla);
    $zahlb = str_replace(',', '.', $zahlb);
    $zahlc = str_replace(',', '.', $zahlc);
    $zahlg = str_replace(',', '.', $zahlg);
    $zahlh = str_replace(',', '.', $zahlh);

    /*Wandle Vars in Floats um */
    $zahla = (float)$zahla;
    $zahlb = (float)$zahlb;
    $zahlc = (float)$zahlc;
    $zahlg = (float)$zahlg;
    $zahlh = (float)$zahlh;

    /*Eigendlicher Code */
    if ($mathe == "drei") {
        if (empty($zahla) or empty($zahlb) or empty($zahlc) or empty($zahlg) or empty($zahlh)) {
            echo 'missing input';
        } else {
            $dr_um = $zahla + $zahlb + $zahlc;
            $dr_fl = ($zahlg * $zahlh) / 2;
            echo '<br>' .
                'Flächeninhalt des Dreiecks: ' . $dr_fl . '<br>' .
                'Umfang des Dreiecks: ' . $dr_um .
                '<br><img src="../pics/rechner/drei.png" alt="dreieck">';
        }
    } elseif ($mathe == "recht") {
        if (empty($zahla) or empty($zahlb)) {
            echo 'missing input';
        } else {
            $re_um = 2 * ($zahla + $zahlb);
            $re_fl = $zahla * $zahlb;
        }
        echo '<br>' .
            'Flächeninhalt des Rechtecks: ' . $re_fl . '<br>' .
            'Umfang des Rechtecks: ' . $re_um .
            '<br><img src="../pics/rechner/recht.jpg" alt="rechteck">';
    } elseif ($mathe == "para") {
        if (empty($zahla) or empty($zahlb) or empty($zahlh)) {
            echo 'missing input';
        } else {
            $pa_um = 2 * $zahla + 2 * $zahlb;
            $pa_fl = $zahla * $zahlh;
            echo '<br>' .
                'Flächeninhalt des Rechtecks: ' . $pa_fl . '<br>' .
                'Umfang des Rechtecks: ' . $pa_um .
                '<br><img src="../pics/rechner/para.png" alt="parallelogramm">';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uff that change comes from another set of changes which I taught I finished. Damn